# Spring Webflow - Problem with converter type

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-webflow

I recently update to spring sts 4 so I'm not sure if something there is causing this issue because I did not have this error before.

I've made sure that that the user object being fetched from the database is a User object and should be passed into the next line of code

ERROR MESSAGE

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type 
[com.paphos.pos.users.Users] to type [@javax.persistence.ManyToOne @javax.persistence.JoinColumn com.paphos.pos.users.Users]
```

WEBFLOW

```
<evaluate result="user" expression="usersService.getCustomerById(1)"></evaluate>
<evaluate expression="order.users = flowScope.user"></evaluate>
```

USERSS

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@StaticMetamodel(Users.class)
public class Users implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int idusers;

private String username;

private String password;

private int enabled = 0;
private String authority;

@Size(max = 25)
private String name;

@Size(min = 10, max = 10)
private String phoneNo;

@Size(min = 10, max = 10)
private String loyalty;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "users")
private List<Timecard> timecard = new ArrayList<>();
```

ORDERS

```
@Entity(name="orders")
public class Orders implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -8538332203504273656L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int idorders;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idusers")
private Users users;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "createdBy")
private Users createdBy;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "driver")
private Users driver;

@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinColumn(name = "idaddresses")
private Addresses addresses;

private double pretax;

private double tax;

private double total;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idstatus")
private Status status;

private String timeOrdered;

private int discounted;
private int tipped;
private Double due;

@OrderColumn
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE }, mappedBy = "orders")
private Set<Orderitem> orderitem;

private double disAmount;
private double tipAmount;
private int paid;
```

I've tried specifying the result as flowscope or any other type of variabel but nothings works. The error is also very confusing because it's the same type just has annotations on it. Maybe it has something to do webflow config because I don't get this error anywhere else. As mentioned above i just updated to sts 4 so im going to go back to version 3 and see if thats the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This error is somehow caused by spring dev tools being in pom.xml. Upon removing it from my code it began to work. Not sure why this is the case though.